# Iframe with external URL, document click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to get the document click on iframe, but it seems its not picking up the document click event, so i tried to generate the iframe click explicitly, it seems working with internal content but when i put the external URL it is not firing the click event,

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://kooldotnet.blogspot.in/2013/07/image-resize.html"></iframe>
```

**Jquery**

```
$('#myframe').load(function(){
  $(this).contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) { alert('test'); });
});
```

[Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/4HQc4/912/)

Please help how should I get IT

**Update**

> When I tried in jsfiddle the ifram src as www.google.com it is
>   working.
>
> Modifying code from @A. Wolf
>
> I got following fiddle
>
> [mouseenter working but not click](http://jsfiddle.net/ttqy13nk/4/)

Thanks

Comment: Possible CORS issue?

Comment: When I tried in jsfiddle the ifram src as www.google.com it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Due to same origin policy, you cannot bind event to content of cross domain iframe (if not explecitely handled by the iframe itself).

Regarding your specific case, binding click event to iframe's body, you could maybe use this workaround:

```
$(focusWindow);

$('iframe').on('mouseenter', function () {
    window.targetedIframe = this;
    $(window).on('blur', iframeclicked);
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(window).off('blur', iframeclicked);
    if($(document.activeElement).is('iframe'))
        focusWindow();
});

function iframeclicked(){
    console.log('iframe clicked', window.targetedIframe);
}

function focusWindow(){
    $('<div/>').attr('tabindex',-1).appendTo('body').focus().remove();
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Please check my jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ttqy13nk/4/ , when i change mouseenter to click, why its not being called, Thanks

Comment: Because you cannot bind click event to iframe but mouseenter/mouseleave/(other list???). So that's the purpose of this workaround even it is not perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/ttqy13nk/6/

Comment: And also if this is the limitation of iframe then why it click event is being registered when i set to google.com